# UIAutomation SetValue not working

Tags: windows, winapi, microsoft-ui-automation

I am using the Windows UIAutomation client API, trying to find a UI element and change its value. When I try to change text values everything seems to work fine. However, I am not able to change any numeric values.

For example, if I try to set the value of the volume slider in Windows Media Player I get the following error in the Inspect tool:

```
Value.SetValue

Called with parameters:
val: 50

Result: 
ERROR - [Error: hr=0xFFFFFFFF80070057 - The parameter is incorrect.]
```

I have verified that the control is enabled, and not readonly. Does this mean that the control doesn't support SetValue, or how am I supposed to format my numeric values? Since the error is `E_INVALIDARG` it seems like I'm just formatting my numeric value incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742106%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a slider should support [IValueProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.provider.ivalueprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which expects a string representation of the numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, it supports string value.
Also,If range value pattern is exposed for that slider, you can get the max allowed value. You can try setting an intermediate value then.